# Alamofire check the data returned

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

How can I check the data, which I get from web service use Alamofire? My code:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters).responseJSON() { (response) -> Void in

        if let jsonResult = response.result.value {
            let Field1 = jsonResult[0]["Field1"] as! String;

         ....
    }
```

If I have the data all is good. But if I don't have data, I have error on string

```
let Field1 = jsonResult[0]["Field1"] as! String;
```

Because my response.result.value is empty. How can I check and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to check length my array "jsonResult" with json data and if it > 0 then work with it.

Answer (score 1):

you should find everything here.

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters).response{
        request,response,data,error in
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            print(json)
            print(response)
            print(request)
            print(error)

            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using .response instead of .responseJSON is a better alternative and gives you the possibility of inspecting the NSData object for debugging purposes, as @Ayush points.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters: parameter, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON   { response in


            //Check Response

            if response.result.isFailure == true {
                return
            }
}
```

Comment: Every time response.result.isFailure is False

Comment: can u check info.plist  app transport security <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>

Comment: I have like this transport security in my info.plist

Comment: you can check    let commonEntity = jsonResult[0]["Field1"]  if commonEntity == nil { return }

Comment: The same error: 2016-02-22 21:08:38.258 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
.....
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

It is on let commonEntity = jsonResult[0]["Field1"];

Response.data is Optional(<5b5d>)
Response.result.value is Optional(())

Comment: I think, I need to check this: response.result.value
But how, I don't know.

Comment: you got any solution ?

Comment: No, I don't know how fix it.